# NSTabViewController as sheet top space

Tags: swift, macos

I'm presenting a NSTabViewController as a sheet. I can't find a way to increase the space between the Toolbar of the presenting Window and the TabViewItem of the sheet view controller. Is there a possibility to adjust this space?

I created a NSTabViewController within the Interface Builder and here's some code how I show it: (the function is within a `NSWindowController`)

```
@IBAction func pressedAddItem(_ sender: Any) {        
        let addItemVC: NSViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("addItemViewController"))
            as! NSViewController
        self.contentViewController?.presentViewControllerAsSheet(addItemVC)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with creating a parent view controller. Means I created a `NSViewController` where I added a ContainerView with the `NSTabViewController`. I don't know if this is a proper solution but it works.. :)

Comment: I had to do it the same way. Besides, the docu doesn't offer much help and googling it showed few solutions to NSTabViewController.